# Using bundle in another one in Symony 2

Tags: php, symfony, components, bundle

I have S2 application with 2 bundles (frontend, backend). Now, I want to create my own component, which I`ll can use in another application (sometimes). Somewhere I read, that in Symfony are components called services.
So I have to create new bundle for my new component/service, right?
And my question is, What i have to do, for use my new component/service, in another bundle(frontend or bakcend)?
Are somewhere any instructions for do this?

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered in the scope of Stack Overflow. See [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html) for information about bundles and [this one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for information about services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no components in symfony , you only have bundles. You can use different bundles in different application.

Suppose you have the `UserBundle` you can use that in any other symfony application as well

You can make the `UserService` inside that Bundle and then can use `UserService` for stuff like

`myservice.updatePassword($password)`

Comment: Thanks, that`s what I wanted to hear. I just was`t sure, if i understand it.